# inverse interpolation

Tags: reference-request, approximation-theory, interpolation, inverse-problems

Given data points $(x_i,y_i)\in \mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>m$ satisfying $y_i=f (x_i)$ with a sufficiently smooth injective unknown function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and a value $y \in Im (f)$, I want to find an estimate for $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ s.t. $f (x)=y$. Does a problem of this sort have a name. Is there any literature available? I am thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Is $f$ known?   Or are there known bounds on its derivatives?

Comment: $f$ is not known. We dont have explicit bounds on $f$ but we know that it is supposed to be a "nice" function with small derivatives. Since this is an applied math problem I could not state a mathematically rigorous problem and there is probably not a unique solution to it. I am looking more towards ways to approach such kinds of problems.

Comment: Isn't this essentially interpolation on $f^{-1}$? (if $f$ is injective --- otherwise there is no unique solution.)

Comment: @Federico Poloni: basically yes, it is also why I called it inverse interpolation. However f^{-1} is defined on Im(f) which is an $m$-dimensional submanifold of $R^n$. So we have to do interpolation on a (unknown) manifold. Furthermore we know that $f$ has small derivatives but not of $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having calculated an "explicit" interpolating function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, satisfying $y_i=f (x_i)$, you can calculate the local inverse via evaluation of the [implicit taylor series](http://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7362/e8c3ce5fc3c10403c5e93aa29e4a79333b0a.pdf) or some other series expansion of implicit functions.

If you are however satisfied with very pragmatic solution, you can chose a data point $(x_i,y_i)$ that minimizes $\|y-y_i\|$ and then via the method of steepest ascend or descent identify the "nearest" $x$, for which $f(x)=y$ w.r.t. the interpolating function $f$; that should also disambiguate the calculation.

If $f$ is smooth, it can be assumed to be (piecewise) polynomial and thus the gradients that are used in the method of steepest ascend or descent can be easily calculated.